# Shall we move to new way of self-assignment protection?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, c++17

All

traditionally, in books on C++ and even in [Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines) the self-assignment protection is written as

```
A& A::operator=(const A& a) {
    if (&a != this) {
       ...
    }
    return *this;
}
```

But in modern C++ (since C++-11) we have [std::addressof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) magic.

If I to teach students all the goodies of modern C++, shall I promote self-assignment check to be written as

```
A& A::operator=(const A& a) {
    if (std::addressof(a) != this) {
       ...
    }
    return *this;
}
```

More general question - should it be the way to go, in Core Guidelines and elsewhere?

Thoughts? Comments?

Comment: You don't need to use `std::addressof()` unless your class overloads `operator&`. A "more modern" way to write `operator=` would be to make sure your class has adequate copy and move constructors, and then merge copy assignment and move assignment into a single `operator=` implementation, letting the compiler decide whether to use copy or move depending on the input, eg: `A& A::operator=(A a) { /* move a into this as needed ... */ return *this; }`

Comment: Do you know the difference between the two?

Comment: @RemyLebeau "You don't need to use std::addressof() unless your class overloads operator&" sorry, it sounds like "you do not need to delete copy ctor for non-copyable class, unless somebody tries to copy object of your class". And how existance of copy/move ctor changes this?

Comment: @Slava That's... not the same thing at all?

Comment: @Barry I think it is similar, if there is way to prevent problems to happen later, why not to use it? What is downside of using `std::addressof()`?

Comment: @Slava It's not the same thing. You delete the copy constructor because you _know_ your class isn't copyable and you want to prevent it from being copied. You use `addressof` in places where you _don't know_ how types you don't own behave.

Comment: @Barry "You use addressof in places where you don't know how types you don't own behave." can you provide citation from C++ standard that claims this?

Comment: @Slava A copy/move constructor has nothing to do with whether you use `std::addressof()` or not. `std::addressof()` gets the address of a variable without using `operator&`. A class is allowed to overload `operator&` to return a memory address to something other than itself (it is not uncommon for various smart pointer implementations to overload `operator&` to return the address of the pointer being held internally).

Comment: Another thing to consider if you are teaching C++ is that the assignment operator very rarely needs to be overloaded.

Comment: @Slava That's not how the standard works - it doesn't tell you how to write code or the motivation for features in the language or library. But that is very much why `addressof` exists.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know what `std::addressof()` does, and OP's question is legit, if using it is simpler why not to do that? Any downsides except longer typing? And I do not understand downvote on legit question.

Comment: @Slava using `std::addressof()` is not *simpler* than using `operator&`, especially when `A` does not overload `operator&`. But, if `A` does overload `operator&` then `std::addressof()` would be *required*, unless `operator=` avoids self assignment altogether by using a copy-and-swap idiom.

Comment: @Barry ok, but you sounded like this is official and anybody that uses `std::addressof()` in other cases must be banned on SO.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I still did not hear what is downside of using `std::addressof()` instead of & in this case. Upside is obvious though.

Comment: @Slava Nobody said there was a *downside* to using it. Just that it is usually not *necessary* to use it. And it is certainly not common practice to use it in most cases. Cases where it *needs* to be used are rare.

Comment: @RemyLebeau writing safer code without any penalty (except size of source code) is necessary enough for me.

Comment: Seems like there's a broader question than protecting against self-assignment here: should `std::addressof()` be used in place of `&` in general?

Comment: @Slava: "*I still did not hear what is downside of using std::addressof() instead of & in this case.*" The downside is that you have to teach people to use a 14-character name that they would otherwise have little need to know about in cases where 99.999% of the time it serves no purpose relative to the 1-character alternative.

Comment: @Slava How did you get from "You use `addressof` in places where you don't know how types you don't own behave" to "anybody that uses `std::addressof()` in other cases must be banned on SO"? Those two statements are not similar.

Comment: @NicolBolas 16 characters :-) parentheses count.

Comment: @Barry I got from downvotes on the question and tone of your and Remy comments. I may get it wrong but it all together really sounds negative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::addressof` is intended for generic code.

In generic code, unary `operator&` could be overloaded by the type you are interacting with.  And if you want the real address, that won't do.

In non-generic code, `operator&` overloading is both rare and pathological.  Anyone who overloads `operator&` on a type is going to make that type extremely weird and will have to audit every use of it anyhow.

The use of unary `operator&` overloading has fallen out of favour -- even pseudo-com smart pointers have gotten out of the habit.  About the only recent use I've seen is someone writing expressions that produce function objects and the like.

Nearly pointless verbosity is not a great thing.